# Order dataframe in R

Tags: r

I want to order de following sequence code

```
         cereal2[Cereal$Calories & Cereal$Carbs <27.5,]
                                    Name Calories Carbs
                 1            AppleJacks      117    27
                 2             Boo Berry      118    27
                 6           Cocoa Puffs      117    26
                 7          Cookie Crisp      117    26
                 8           Corn Flakes      101    24
                 10              Crispix      113    26
                 12          Froot Loops      118    26
                 17         King Vitaman       80    17
                 18                  Kix       87    20
                 20         Lucky Charms      114    25
                 21 Multi-Grain Cheerios      108    24
                 22           Product 19      100    25
                 25            Rice Chex       94    22
                 28            Special K      117    22
                 30             Wheaties      107    24
```

How can I sort the calories in ascending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one liner in base R :)

```
df <- df[order(df$Calories),]
```